# Mediawiki - Display languages chooser on the sidebar (left)

Tags: mediawiki, multilingual, translate

I have install MediaWiki with Xamp. But my wiki content must be in English and in French. I want a menu on the left (like Wikipedia) for choose the language.

I have found this : https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Interwiki#Setting_up_interlanguage_links

but it's not clear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Could you please ask a specific question instead of saying "it's not clear"?

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of research and test a lot of extensions i have found the solution :

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Polyglot